# Reading blank cells of excel and returning List<List<String>>

Tags: java, apache-poi

my excel file has 4 rows and 2 columns like 
with continuous values having 3row 1st column as blank value like given below

```
phone       plan
------------------
85366667777 PLATINUM
85367890000 GOLD
85362524232 SILVER
null        SILVER
85362522436 DIAMOND
```

---

```
public List<List<String>> readExcelFile(String fileName) {

        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            POIFSFileSystem fsFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(fileInputStream);
            HSSFWorkbook workBook = new HSSFWorkbook(fsFileSystem);
            HSSFSheet hssfSheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = hssfSheet.rowIterator();
            boolean headerRow = true;
            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                if (headerRow == false) {
                String Rows = util.loadfile("config/ConfigValue.properties","NoOfRowsToSkip");
                int i = Integer.parseInt(Rows);
                    HSSFRow hssfRow = (HSSFRow) rowIterator.next();
                    if(hssfRow.getRowNum()==0||hssfRow.getRowNum()<=i){
                           continue; //just skip the rows if row number is 0 TO i
                          }
                    Iterator<Cell> iterator = hssfRow.cellIterator();
                    List cellTempList = new ArrayList();
                    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                        HSSFCell hssfCell = (HSSFCell) iterator.next();

                    if(hssfCell.getCellType() == hssfCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)
                        {DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#");
                        String cellValue=df.format(hssfCell.getNumericCellValue());
                        cellTempList.add(cellValue.toString());

                        }
                         else if(hssfCell.getCellType() == hssfCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
                         {
                         cellTempList.add(hssfCell.toString());
                     }

                    }

                    cellDataList.add(cellTempList);
                } else {
                    headerRow = false;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.error("Other Exception : " + e.getStackTrace());
        }
        System.out.println(cellDataList); 
        return cellDataList;
    }
    }
```

output : `[[85366667777, PLATINUM], [85367890000, GOLD], [85362524232, SILVER], [SILVER], [85362522436, DIAMOND]]`

Why it is not printing `[null,Silver]` or `[0,SILVER]` when there is no value in  its corresponding cell ?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(hssfCell.getCellType() == hssfCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC){
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#");
    String cellValue=df.format(hssfCell.getNumericCellValue());
    cellTempList.add(cellValue.toString());
} else if(hssfCell.getCellType() == hssfCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING){
    cellTempList.add(hssfCell.toString());
} else {
    cellTempList.add(null);  // or cellTempList.add("0");
}
```

Your empty cell is neither string nor numeric, so nothing is added to your array. Try checking for CELL_TYPE_BLANK.

Comment: so what can be done in order to add blank values into my array

Comment: See my above edit. Check for CELL_TYPE_BLANK and write an empty value (null, 0, "" - whatever makes sense for your code) to the array element.

Comment: i have added this block but its not working if(hssfCell.getCellType()==hssfCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK)
       {
      
       cellTempList.add(0);
      }

Comment: If you are looking for string output, wrap that 0 in quotes.

Comment: sorry gray its not working. Its not at all executing that condition.

Comment: If none of the conditions are executing, change that `else if` to just an `else`. It should be CELL_TYPE_BLANK, but this change should eliminate any other possibility.

Comment: numeric and string check is working fine both the conditions are executing. blank condition is not executing

Comment: If you've changed the `else if` to an `else` then one of those three conditions should be executing on your blank cell. Which one is it?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a `Iterator` to iterate over the cells.  But if a cell never had a value, it likely does not exist.  In this case, there is only one cell over which to iterate.

If you want to maintain an iterator, then you'll need to test the column index of the cell on which you're iterating.  If there is no 0-column cell, then you can handle that case by adding in your own `null` or `0` first.

But it sounds easier to remove the iterator and directly access the cells with columns 0 and 1 with the [`getCell` method that takes a `MissingCellPolicy`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getCell%28int,%20org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row.MissingCellPolicy%29).

```
Cell zero = hssfRow.getCell(0, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
Cell one  = hssfRow.getCell(1, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
```

This will create a blank `Cell` if it did not exist.  Then you can test if the cell has a `CELL_TYPE_BLANK` cell type and act accordingly.

Comment: if i want to use iterator only ..is there is any way that i could do some logic inside the loop ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use Missing Cell Policy. In some cases, when iterating, you need full control over how missing or blank cells are treated, and you need to ensure you visit every cell and not just those defined in the file. In cases such as you have mentioned, you should fetch the first and last column information for a row, then call getCell(int, MissingCellPolicy) to fetch the cell. Use a [MissingCellPolicy](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.MissingCellPolicy.html) to control how blank or null cells are handled.

Take an example where rows are like

[image]

Here A2 is null, insted of blank, as in your case. Here you need to assign cell value as `Cell cell = row.getCell(int arg0, MissingCellPolicy arg1): Cell-Row`

There are three types of MissingCellPolicy as

`CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK`,`CREATE_BLANK_AS_NULL` and `RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK`

Use it as following

```
for (int i = 0; i<3 ;i++){
    for(int j=0 ; j<2; j++){
        Row row = sheet1.getRow(i);
        Cell cell = row.getCell(j, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
//              Cell cell = row.getCell(j, Row.RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK);
//              if(row.getCell(j)==null){
//                  System.out.print("Null ");
//              }else
            System.out.print(cell.toString()+" - ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Here whenever any cell with null value is encountered, then `Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK` return the cell value with BLANK. instead of throwing `NullPointerException`. In this case the output will be

```
A1 - B1 - 
 - B2 - 
A3 - B3 -
```

If you use `Row.RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK`, then it will return Null in case of any cell is not defined. so you need to create a null check (As commented in code). in this case Output will be

```
 A1 - B1 - 
 Null B2 - 
 A3 - B3 -
```

Comment: should i need to remove the iterator den...?

Comment: i tried with missingcellpolicy its working but i want to use iterator only how it could be done ?please help

Comment: what about if whole row is blank and after that again my table has value A1 - B1 - 
 -  - -
 A3 - B3

Comment: @akash: sorry for delayed response: I think missingCellPolicy will work for iterator as well. As well as If you are aware that in your condition null or blank row (both are different) may exist, you need to check the row before getting any cell of that row.
Row row=sheet1.getRow(rowNum);     if(row!=null){ //now get the cell values}